# How to view historical banner notifications on macOS?

Tags: macos, notifications

I often see banner notifications - which disappear after about two seconds - and then wonder:

- how can I view them again?
- which application generated them?

I would be looking for a way to scroll through a reverse- chronologically ordered list of banner notifications regardless of how/by which app they were generated.

Is this possible?